# How to connect SignalR to Extjs application?

Tags: c#, extjs, signalr

I've been trying to get signalR to trigger in my application when my database is updated.
Here is how I'm trying to implement it:

```
private const string SignalRJobStatusHubName = "jobControlHub";
private const string SignalRJobControlCreatedMethod = "jobControlCreated";
private const string SignalRJobControlUpdatedMethod = "jobControlUpdated";

private ISignalRService _signalRService;
private ISignalRService SignalRService => _signalRService ?? (_signalRService = ObjectFactory.CreateInstance<ISignalRService>());
```

Then when DB is updated, at the end of the Tryinsert method:

```
var inserted = DatabaseContext.Current.Execute(sql) > 0;

if (inserted)
{
    await SendSignalRMessageAsync(new ServerJobControlSignalDto(jobControl), SignalRJobControlCreatedMethod);
}
```

Finally to tie it all up:

```
private async Task<bool> SendSignalRMessageAsync(ServerJobControlSignalDto serverJobControlNotification, string method) =>
      await SignalRService.TenantBroadcastAsync(SignalRJobStatusHubName, new SignalNotification
      {
          Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serverJobControlNotification),
          TargetMethod = method
      }, CurrentTenant.TenantId);
```

Now in my Extjs I have this constructor:

```
 constructor: function (grid) {
    var me = this;

    me.jobMonitoringGrid = grid;

    Comp.signaling.getHub('jobControlHub').then(function (jobControlHub) {
        me.jobControlHub = jobControlHub;
        me.jobCreatedHandler = me.onJobControlCreated.bind(me);
        me.jobUpdatedHandler = me.onJobControlUpdated.bind(me);

        jobControlHub.on('jobControlCreated', me.jobCreatedHandler);
        jobControlHub.on('jobControlUpdated', me.jobUpdatedHandler);
    });
},
```

Then I have some functions on the same file to update the store and store model with the signal received (ServerJobControlSignalDto). After that I have a grid using one of the values from the DTO as dataIndex. I can provide more code if you need but I'm trying to avoid just posting a useless wall of code for now.
The problem is that the grid is not taking any value whatsoever when I update the database. It's returning 0 for all rows.
I'm new to signalR and basically copied an implementation on another page of my company application for a different DB entity/manager. In that page, with 99% similar code, it is working fine and sending/receiving db updates. I get the gist of what signalR is supposed to do. I tried following some tutorials and asking around my company for some clarification but the people responsible for implementing this aren't with the company anymore.
Is there anything else I usually need to do to make signalR work with code or configs, taking in consideration that the entity manager implementation that I copied from works perfectly fine and mine doesn't?
Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: So do you have the data in the Ext JS store and you have problem with showing it in the grid or you don't event get the data?

Comment: What does your SignalR client tell you? Are you connected? Do you have access to the hub? If so, try enabling the transport logs and see if they give you any details.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I think I don't even have the data. I placed an alert during the update store function and, whilst updating the db, it was not triggered. Also I'm trying to pass the object message's log level to a column value but it's returning as 0 in the console log as well. So I think I'm not getting the data, but not 100% sure because I'm a noob at this.

Comment: I don't know how your model, store and proxy is implemented, but if you used a code that was designed for a different data source, my guess is that you have a problem in the proxy.

Comment: I debugged every step of the way and it seems the signal is being sent.
The problem may be in the way I'm storing it.
At the moment I'm trying to update just 1 var of a store with it which indexes to just 1 column of a table. This store and table is being set by that previous table entity I mentioned that is working fine. Do I need to create a new model and store if I want to set this extra column and var with another entity through signalR or can I use signalR to set it and update the previous store? Maybe I should create another question and delete this one?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by using the same hub name as the previously implemented manager had, but with my own methods.
It seems I couldn't just create another hub, I needed to add it to a list of available/usable ones.